# Bluer or more blue in "its more blue offerings can get steamier"?

Tags: vocabulary, comparative-constructions

As I know, a monosyllabic adjective is usually made comparative with -er, while polysyllabic adjective is usually made comparative with word more. The problem is that I found [an article](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Josei) that uses word "more blue" to refer to something that is closer to pornographic material. Is this correct?

> Romance is more nuanced here than the Shoujo style of "never been kissed", with its heroines often either unlucky in love, working through relationship troubles, or generally experienced. On the flip side, its **more blue** offerings (known as "Ladies Comics") can get steamier than even the most borderline Teens Love — harems getting sexual, pent-up coworkers, women with "pet"-like subordiates — with a subgenre even dedicated to adapting Harlequin romance.

Comment: Blue there means erotic.  But it is not exactly very common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a “problem” at all. English often follows conventions where exceptions abound.

I would reword your assertion:

> a monosyllabic adjective usually **can be** made comparative with -*er*, while a polysyllabic adjective **that doesn’t end with *y*** is usually made comparative with the word *more*

However, just because a word **can** be made comparative with -*er* doesn’t mean it **must** be made comparative that way.

In fact, an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greener%2Cmore%20green%2Cbluer%2Cmore%20blue&year_start=1960&year_end=1980&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows that, although *bluer* and *greener* are more common than *more blue* and *more green*, there are still plenty of instances of the latter.

It’s also worth considering that many colors like *green* or *blue* can have other meanings besides the color itself (such as *ecofriendly* and *pornographic*). This might influence whether or not a writer believes that *more red* sounds better than *redder* in a certain context:

> Since 2008, Texas has consistently become more red, not less.[<sup>1</sup>](https://www.theepochtimes.com/dont-bet-on-beto_2700426.html)

That all said, you wouldn’t want to use *more* or *-er* to make comparative adjectives indiscriminately. Some combinations just wouldn’t make good sense:

> The company sold <strike>more few</strike> cars last year.
>   The company sold **fewer** cars last year.
>
> Seattle is <strike>norther</strike> than Toronto.
>   Seattle is **more north** than Toronto.
>   (even better, I think): Seattle is **further** north than Toronto.

Comment: Actually, I know that some color adjectives sometimes are used in non-color meaning. However, the problem is "is that adjective in that meaning gets comparative in -er or more?"

Comment: It could go either way; e.g., see the article [_Building with a more durable, greener concrete_](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/report-on-business/small-business/sb-growth/building-with-a-more-durable-greener-concrete/article4301342/), which says: _The cement industry, however, has been working on becoming more green._ There’s no right or wrong way to do this.

Comment: so the answer is both.